# React fetch method is returning json as object rather than array

Tags: reactjs, fetch

In my main component, I am fetching the api data and setting it to a state.  Rather than an object, I'd prefer it to be in an array.  Is there any way I can do this during the fetch and just make the object the first index(and only) index in an array?

```
fetch('https://api.aes/latest')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({ 
      launchData: json,
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`React#spread operator`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) on object.

```
.then(json => {
        this.setState({ 
          launchData: [...json],
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
fetch('https://api.aes/latest')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({ 
      launchData: [json],
  });
```